# how to change images on a gridview?

Tags: android

I'm using a Gridview to display a set of images. What I want to do is that when the user taps on one image, it displays an effect that shows the user that some information is being trasmitted wirelessly and when the phone receives such information the image returns to its original state. Something similar to an animated gif.

This is the code I have until now for the onclick event:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     new Thread(new sendingThread()).start();
  }
```

});

At the moment I have a blue shadow over the image as the only onclick event effect, which i'd like to get rid of and substitute for the one I've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AniamtionDrawable, you can either embed it into a single item of a gridview and set it to View.VISIBLE then View.GONE or inflate and add it on top of it. 
Not sure which one will be the least expensive one.
To preempt the further question. Start the animation upon a view gaining the focus.

I'd also keep track of which buttons are already tapped/selected via SparseBooleanArray within the adapter. You don't want to spawn too many threads, do you?